# CaseId is not associated to LiveChatTranscript record as expected

Tags: liveagent, omnichannel, chat, deployment-api, livechattranscript

I'm using the Live Agent Deployment API to trigger the live chat flow, before initialize the chat window we also run **saveToTranscript** to associate a Case to LiveChatTranscript by filling the case id, the following is our code:

```
liveagent.findOrCreate('Case').map('CaseNumber', 'Case Number', true, true, true).saveToTranscript('CaseId');
liveagent.init(chatSettings.chat.endpointUrl, chatSettings.chat.deploymentId, chatSettings.chat.organizationId);
```

In most cases, this flow is working correctly(CaseId field is filled correctly in LiveChatTranscript) without any issue, but don't know why there are still some LiveChatTranscript records that generated in Salesforce has Completed status while their CaseId field is empty:

[image]

I also looked into some of those problematic LiveChatTranscript records in detail and their history, they have nothing in common(Different browsers/device), and all other fields are correctly filled except for the CaseId, which appears to me that the conversation between agents and visitor goes well.

Is there anyone encountered such issue or has any insight how we can debug it further?

By the way, we have no any Trigger/Workflow/Process for LiveChatTranscript

Very appreciate any thoughts around this.

Comment: did you end up raising a ticket to SFDC Support? If so, what was the outcome?

Comment: Finally, this issue fixed by change the javascript, instead of using CaseNumber to map a case then save it to transcript, we are using Id of case to map a case directly.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue on our Org. We already opened a ticket with Salesforce.

So wish you/us luck. Thing has escalated already.

Workaround is to use an on before trigger on the LiveChatTranscript to manually create the Case.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info, probably I will also submit a ticket to push them a bit as well ;).
The workaround I have in mind is to made additional ajax call from visitor's Live Chat window to our api and try to sync the CaseId into LiveChatTranscript via ChatKey.

Comment: @tugamaster, did you receive any root cause analysis from Salesforce on this? If you could, please share the details how it was fixed because we're facing exactly the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I am using chat rest api to do chat initiation and I got the same issue. We attach the CaseId and ContactId during chat initiation and those values are exist on UI, however, when I put log on LiveChatTranscript trigger, those two fields are null.

After investigation, I found a workaround to get CaseId and ContactId. Here are few steps that I did to get that value:

1. Create to custom fields to store the value. In my case (CaseId__c and ContactId__c)
2. During chat initiation (on your [chasitorInit][1] request body), you can put those field values on `transcriptFields` under `CustomDetail`.

Here are the examples:

```
 "prechatDetails": [
                {"label": "CaseId", "value": "5000w000003Ht3aAAC", "transcriptFields": ["CaseId__c"], "displayToAgent": "true"},
                {"label": "ContactId", "value": "0030w00000N7TlvAAF", "transcriptFields": ["ContactId__c"], "displayToAgent": "true"},
            ],
            "prechatEntities": [
                {
                    "entityName": "Case",
                    "showOnCreate": "true",
                    "linkToEntityName": "Case",
                    "linkToEntityField": "Id",
                    "saveToTranscript": "Case",
                    "entityFieldsMaps": [
                        {
                            "fieldName": "Id",
                            "label": "CaseId",
                            "doFind": "true",
                            "isExactMatch": "true",
                            "doCreate": "false",
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "entityName": "Contact",
                    "showOnCreate": "true",
                    "linkToEntityName": "Contact",
                    "linkToEntityField": "Id",
                    "saveToTranscript": "Contact",
                    "entityFieldsMaps": [
                        {
                            "fieldName": "Id",
                            "label": "ContactId",
                            "doFind": "true",
                            "isExactMatch": "true",
                            "doCreate": "false",
                        }
                    ],
                },
            ],

[1]: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_request_bodies.htm#ChasitorInit
```