# Lack of CaseId on LiveChatTranscript

Tags: liveagent, omnichannel, chat, livechattranscript

**TL;DR**: For some LiveChatTranscript records, CaseId is empty although standard Salesforce functionality is used and Case is created before Chat is ended.

Although this problem was already mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253150/caseid-is-not-associated-to-livechattranscript-record-as-expected), there wasn't any conclusion on root cause analysis.

Unfortunately, I'm facing exactly the same problem now and, because this is just a standard Salesforce feature, there's not much that end user can do about it. Salesforce Support Case is already reported but I'm wondering if you've encountered this problem as well.

[image]

This is especially problematic because there is no easy way to fix affected records because sometimes lack of CaseId might be normal but sometimes not so this requires a lot of manual effort to fix the data when we have dozens of hundreds of LiveChatTranscript records.

[image]

Comment: I vaguely remember seeing this before. Is it right that the Case is only created if the LiveChat is 'answered' (or accepted, I can't remember the standard stage name)?

Comment: @DanWareing, in our scenario Agents are creating Cases manually (once LiveChat session is initiated). This is mostly because not every LiveChat session would end up with a Case being created. So, in situations when we are sure that Case was created before LiveChat was ended, we are still not getting CaseId reference populated on LiveChatTranscript records.

Comment: I remember something about silent failures being possible at some step in the linkage, but it will be very difficult for anyone but a support rep with login access to assist you.

Comment: @belford - Can you confirm whether this is just some or all instances? I think I mis-remembered earlier, and now recall something about the LiveChatTranscript record now technically being 'inserted' until some strange point in time, like it being closed by the agent (in which case, your Case linking might be failing because the LCT doesn't have an Id yet).

Comment: @DanWareing, currently, only one production environment is impacted. However, this is the environment where LiveChat is extensively used so such random situations are more likely to happen. We tried to reproduce it on our dev environments but no luck so far. Salesforce Case has been already escalated but, after a week, we haven't received any response yet.